# use spree_application layout within a new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm trying to use the spree_application layout in a controller that i've just add to my spree app

```
class ShotsController < Spree::BaseController

  layout 'spree_application'

  def index
    @shots = Shot.all
  end

  def show
    @shot=Shot.find(params[:id])
  end   

end
```

but when i'm trying to go to shots_path
i've got an error:

```
NoMethodError in Shots#index

Showing /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/spree_core-    1.3.2/app/views/spree/shared/_nav_bar.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined method `current_order' for #< ShotsController:0x007f9c6b746e40>
```

does anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

ok just figure out how:

include Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order in the application_controller.rb file

Answer (score 0):

If you want your controller to be a part of the Spree core, try moving its file into `app/controllers/spree/` and rewrite it as below:

```
module Spree
  class ShotsController < ApplicationController
    layout 'spree_application'

    def index
      @shots = Shot.all
    end

    def show
      @shot=Shot.find(params[:id])
    end   
  end
end
```